# Rewrite URL for blog-detail.php/{slug} into blog-detail/{slug}

Tags: php, .htaccess, indexing, url-rewriting, seo

i have successfully rewrite www.my-website/blog.php into just www.my-website/blog

Now, i want to do further things to my blog-detail.php page
from www.my-website/blog-detail.php/how-seo-works into www.my-website/blog-detail/how-seo-works

'**how-seo-works**' is my slug and it can be anything depends on article's title

When i tried the **www.my-website/blog-detail/how-seo-works** 
the error is Internal Server Error

Here's my htaccess:

```
# Run Php without filename extension
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

# Return 404 if original request is .php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^[^ ]* .*?\.php[? ].*$"
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=404]
```

the error appears in website:

> Internal Server Error
>   The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at you@example.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
>
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

in Error logs:
AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: http://localhost:8080/my-website/blog

Comment: First of all: The _first_ thing you _always_ do on a 500 Internal Server Error, is you go check the error log to get an actual error message that has some detail about what went wrong.

Comment: Comment out 2 lines below `# Return 404` and retest.

Comment: i have comment out those 2 lines, but it doesn't affect anything, 
for the error logs, i have updated the logs @CBroe

Comment: You probably don’t have a folder named `blog-detail/how-seo-works` and no file named `blog-detail/how-seo-works.php` either, so this should pass the first block of conditions & rules unaffected. And the original request did contain `.php` either, so the second block should leave it alone as well. It is currently not apparent how this should do _any_ rewriting for the given example URL, and how you would not just get a plain old 404 with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem.

So, here's my modified .htaccess to access my-website/blog-detail/how-seo-work

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^blog-detail/([0-9a-zA-Z-]+) blog-detail.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^[^ ]* .*?\.php[? ].*$"
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=404]
```